# How can I get My entire BottomSheetDialog to show above my keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialog, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheetDialog` that pops up on click of a button. The `Dialog` contains an `EditText`, and on the focus of that `EditText`, the Dialogs Pans only up to the `EditText`, Leaving my Submit button below it hidden

[image: The BottomSheetDialog]

My Code:

```
mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MyActivity.this);
sheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_bottom_sheet, null);
mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(myView);
mBottomSheetDialog.show();
```

I have Tried using `adjustPan`, but that only works up to the `EditText`, whereas I want it to my Submit button

Comment: Did you try `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. when I did it, the soft keyboard popped up automatically as dialog is called, but still above the button

Comment: Maybe change your root tag in XML? To `FrameLayout ` --> `ScrollView ` --> your other code with `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE `.

Comment: No, that did not make a difference