# Is it possible to bring the android keyboaord to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to bring the android keyboard to the bottom of the screen rather than to stay in the bottom of the screen ,

Since my buttons are not visible when the keyboard appears in the bottom of the android layout and I do not want the button to be in the top but I want the keyboard to appear to the top of the screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531811/push-whole-dialog-above-the-keyboard-keyboard-covers-button/55531939#55531939   check here my answer

Answer (score 0):

put this in the manifest file, will adjust your views and make user interaction easy

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.example.myactivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Comment: No this did not helped me .I want the keyboard to be displayed in the top rather than displaying in the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the bottom layout will hide when the soft keyboard popup

```
 rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int heightDiff = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - rootLayout.getHeight();
                if (heightDiff > Utilities.convertDpToPixel(200, ReportDetailsActivity.this)) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
                    // ... do something here
                    ll_bottom_navigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else ll_bottom_navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```